# Ввод и вывод в одну строку на Python

Tags: python

Есть код

```
while True:
try:
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    c = a + b
    print(c)
except ValueError:
    continue
else:
    break
```

который выводит

```
2 2 #это числа введены пользователем
4 #это результат
```

как сделать чтобы вывод происходил на одной строке с вводом через пробел? вот так

```
2 2 4
```

Answer (score 5):

После того, как пользователь завершит ввод, в любом случае произойдёт перевод строки. Но можно вернуться на предыдущую строку вот так:

```
import sys

a, b = map(int, input().split())
c = a + b
sys.stdout.write("\x1b[1A")
sys.stdout.write('{} {} {}'.format(a, b, c))
```

Правда, с обработкой некорректных значений тут сложнее. Даже если как в вашем примере всё это дело обернуть в `try ... except`, то у меня всё рано пока не получается избавиться от ввода, оставшегося с предыдущей итерации.

UPD: Сейчас подумал, что можно чистить остатки предыдущий итерации ДО инпута. Но в этом случае нужно отслеживать - а была ли предыдущая итерация или сейчас пока первая:

```
import sys

is_first_try = True

while True:
    try:
        if not is_first_try:
            sys.stdout.write("\x1b[1A" + " "*20 + "\b"*20)
        is_first_try = False
        a, b = map(int, input().split())
        c = a + b
        sys.stdout.write("\x1b[1A")
        sys.stdout.write('{} {} {}'.format(a, b, c))
    except ValueError:
        continue
    else:
        break
```